# Scale font using css whether width or height changes

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am aware of vh/vw or wmin/vmax units. But still with that I can't scale font whether my width or height changes. That is, I can scale font using css only in one case - if I want to scale font when width changes, then I use vw, for height vh. Is there something that I can use for both cases?

For both cases you can use css logic:

```
width:100vw;
height:50vw;
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 200vh;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is only a vmin and vmax.

> vmin unit Equal to the smaller of ‘vw’ or ‘vh’.
>
> vmax unit Equal to the larger of ‘vw’ or ‘vh’.

[via http://www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

Answer (score 1):

1. 1vw = 1% of viewport width
2. 1vh = 1% of viewport height
3. 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
4. 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger